# How to merge a part of several lists in 3 differents dict

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, merge

For a little project, I have to make requests to an API et I get differents results, I need to merge a part of these results, the "count", in the same dict/list or anyway

I tried this (and it works) but I'm sure there is a better way, more pythonic

Result expected:

```
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo','counta': '110','countb': '26','countc': '72'}, 
 {'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar','counta': '810','countb': '53','countc': '42'}]
```

1st request result:

```
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo','count': '110'}, 
 {'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar','count': '810'}]
```

2nd request result:

```
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo','count': '26'}, 
 {'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar','count': '53'}]
```

3rd request result:

```
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo','count': '72'}, 
 {'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar','count': '42'}]

servers_list = []


for ida in first_request:
    for idb in second_request:
        if ida['id'] == idf['id']:
            for idc in third_request:
                if idc['id'] == ida['id']:

                    total = {'id': ida['offer_id'],
                        'descr': ida['offer_description'],
                        'a': ida['count'],
                        'b': idb['count'],
                        'c': idc['count']

                        }


    slist.append(total)
```

Thank you in advance for you help :)

Comment: What's the issue? If you are just looking for optimization you are in the wrong site.

Comment: I don't know if we can call that "optimization", but a better way to do do the same thing yes

Comment: You are in the wrong place if you are asking how to refactor this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use `pandas`. Convert your lists of dictionaries into dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame(first_result)
d2 = ...
d3 = ...
```

Join them into a new wide dataframe with redundant columns:

```
d = d1.join(d2,rsuffix='b').join(d3,rsuffix='c')

#  count descr   id countb descrb  idb countc descrc  idc
#0   110   foo  109     26    foo  109     72    foo  109
#1   810   bar  114     53    bar  114     42    bar  114
```

Remove the duplicate columns:

```
d.drop(['idb','idc','descrb','descrc'], axis=1, inplace = True)
```

Convert the result back to the list of dictionaries:

```
list(d.T.to_dict().values())
#[{'countc': '72', 'count': '110', 'descr': 'foo', 'countb': '26', 'id': 109}, 
# {'countc': '42', 'count': '810', 'descr': 'bar', 'countb': '53', 'id': 114}]
```

Comment: This is perfect :) Exactly does what I need, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution without dependency on additional modules.

```
# input data

results = [
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo','count': '110'}, 
 {'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar','count': '810'}],
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo','count': '26'}, 
 {'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar','count': '53'}],
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo','count': '72'}, 
 {'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar','count': '42'}]
]

COPY_KEYS = ['id', 'descr']
MERGE_KEYS = ['count']
MERGE_SUFFIXES = [chr(o) for o in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]

# basic setup for our data structure

merged = [{} for _ in results[0]]

# copy fixed keys

# as these keys are the same for all results, just steal from the first
for i_result_row, result_row in enumerate(results[0]):
  for key in COPY_KEYS:
    merged[i_result_row][key] = result_row[key]

# copy dynamic keys

for i_result, result in enumerate(results):
  for i_result_row, result_row in enumerate(result):
    for key in MERGE_KEYS:
      merged[i_result_row][key + MERGE_SUFFIXES[i_result]] = result_row[key]

# output

print("Expected result:")
print("[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo', 'counta': '110', 'countb': '26', 'countc': '72'}, ")
print("{'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar', 'counta': '810', 'countb': '53', 'countc': '42'}]")

print("Actual result:")
print(str(merged).replace('}, {', '},\n{'))
```

As output I get this:

```
Expected result:
[{'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo', 'counta': '110', 'countb': '26', 'countc': '72'}, 
{'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar', 'counta': '810', 'countb': '53', 'countc': '42'}]
Actual result:
[{'counta': '110', 'id': 109, 'descr': 'foo', 'countc': '72', 'countb': '26'},
{'counta': '810', 'id': 114, 'descr': 'bar', 'countc': '42', 'countb': '53'}]
```

Due to hasing, the order of keys may vary for Python <3.6.